# Getting the same "key" for a tuple (Python)

Tags: python-2.7, hash

I have a tuple that is `(a, b, c)`. I want to get a common value to use as a key from this tuple, and I thought of something like hashing. For example, `(a, b, c)` and `(b, a, c)` should both give me the same hash value. However, I tried to hash (1, 2, 3) and (2, 1, 3) and ended up with different hash values.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about sort the tuple first? All permutations would become the same tuple after sorting and thus give the same hash value.